# Create a datatable column between two column in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a Datatable. For example :

```
private DataTable GetGenericDatatable(){
    DataTable retval = new DataTable();
    retval.Columns.Add("ProtocolNumber");
    retval.Columns.Add("Name");
    retval.Columns.Add("Company");
    retval.Columns.Add("Department");
    retval.Columns.Add("VisitDate");
    retval.Columns.Add("DispatchTargetName");
    retval.Columns.Add("DayOffCount");
    // add data ...
    return retval;
}
```

I want to insert some columns between **"Department"** and **"VisitDate"** columns dynamically even the datatable is full with data.

We can do this by creating new datatable, creating the columns again etc. but it is a dirty solution. Any idea for a clear solution?

Comment: Please look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937516/datatable-column-reorder

Comment: @Raghu Yes, it looks good but sometimes inserted columns count may be over 30+, and rewrite 30+ columns again sounds not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a [`DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) to the `DataColumm`:

```
DataTable tbl = GetGenericDatatable();
tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1") { DefaultValue="def. value"});
tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(DateTime)) { DefaultValue = DateTime.Now });
```

This value will be applied to every existing row in the table.

You can use `SetOrdinal` to set the index of a column. For example:

```
tbl.Columns["Col1"].SetOrdinal(tbl.Columns.IndexOf("VisitDate"));
tbl.Columns["Col2"].SetOrdinal(tbl.Columns.IndexOf("VisitDate"));
```

Now the new columns are between `Department` and `VisitDate`, `Col1` before `Col2`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new `DataColumn` and use the [`SetOrdinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.setordinal(v=vs.110).aspx) method to set its position:

```
var col = retval.Columns.Add("New Column");
col.SetOrdinal(4);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. 1 Up

Answer (score 1):

You could use this Extension:

```
namespace System
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void AddColumnAfter(this DataColumnCollection columnCollection, string afterWhichColumn, DataColumn column)
        {
            var columnIndex = columnCollection.IndexOf(afterWhichColumn);
            columnCollection.Add(column);
            columnCollection[column.ColumnName].SetOrdinal(columnIndex + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 table.Columns.Add("Column 1");
 table.Columns.Add("Column 2");
 table.Columns.Add("Column 3");
 table.Columns.AddColumnAfter("Column 1", new DataColumn("Column 4"));
```